# Fast portable, parallel MSD radix sort for unsigned keys in C89

Tags: c, multithreading, sorting, radix-sort, c89

Now I have this portable, parallel MSD radix sort for `unsigned` keys. It exhibits linear speedup on small values of \$P\$ and has a running time of
$$
\Theta(N/P + P),
$$
where \$P\$ is the number of processors available.

What comes to portability, my implementation runs on Windows, Linux and macOSX.

The entire project lives [in GitHub](https://github.com/coderodde/C.Radixsort); it contains the files for Visual Studio 2022 and a funky Makefile for *nix. My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#else
#error "Unsupported platform."
#endif

#define MIN(a, b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define BUCKETS 256

static const size_t BITS_PER_BUCKET = 8;
static const size_t BUCKET_MASK = 0xff;
static const size_t MERGESORT_THRESHOLD = 4096;
static const size_t INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD = 16;
static const size_t THREAD_THRESHOLD = 65536;

/******************************************************************************
* Array list data structure.                                                  *
******************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    void** data;
    size_t size;
} array_t;

static void array_t_init(array_t* array, size_t capacity) {
    array->size = 0;
    array->data = malloc(capacity * sizeof(void*));
}

static void array_t_add(array_t* array, void* datum) {
    array->data[array->size++] = datum;
}

static void* array_t_get(array_t* array, size_t index) {
    return array->data[index];
}

static void array_t_shuffle(array_t* array) {
    size_t i;
    size_t j;
    void* temp;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i != array->size - 1; ++i) {
        j = i + rand() % (array->size - i);
        temp = array->data[i];
        array->data[i] = array->data[j];
        array->data[j] = temp;
    }
}

static size_t array_t_size(array_t* array) {
    return array->size;
}

static void array_t_destruct(array_t* array) {
    free(array->data);
}

/******************************************************************************
* Thread-specific data structures.                                            *
******************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    size_t local_bucket_size_map[BUCKETS];
    unsigned* source;
    size_t recursion_deph;
    size_t from_index;
    size_t to_index;
} bucket_size_counter_thread_data;

typedef struct {
    unsigned* source;
    unsigned* target;
    size_t* start_index_map;
    size_t* processed_map;
    size_t recursion_depth;
    size_t from_index;
    size_t to_index;
} bucket_inserter_thread_data;

typedef struct {
    unsigned* source;
    unsigned* target;
    size_t threads;
    size_t recursion_depth;
    size_t from_index;
    size_t to_index;
} task;
/******************************************************************************
* End of data structures.                                                     *
******************************************************************************/

size_t get_number_of_cpus() {
#ifdef _WIN32
    SYSTEM_INFO system_info;
    GetSystemInfo(&system_info);
    return (size_t) system_info.dwNumberOfProcessors;
#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))
    return (size_t) sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
#endif
}

static size_t get_bucket_index(unsigned datum, size_t recursion_depth) {
    size_t bit_shift = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned) -
        (recursion_depth + 1) * BITS_PER_BUCKET;

    return (((size_t) datum) >> bit_shift) & BUCKET_MASK;
}

static void parallel_radix_sort_impl(unsigned* source,
                                     unsigned* target,
                                     size_t threads,
                                     size_t recursion_depth,
                                     size_t from_index,
                                     size_t to_index);

static void radix_sort_impl_no_threads(unsigned* source,
                                       unsigned* target,
                                       size_t recursion_depth,
                                       size_t from_index,
                                       size_t to_index);

static void process_bucket_size_counter_thread(
    bucket_size_counter_thread_data* data) {

    size_t i;

    memset(data->local_bucket_size_map, 0, BUCKETS * sizeof(size_t));

    for (i = data->from_index; i != data->to_index; ++i) {
        data->local_bucket_size_map[
            get_bucket_index(
                data->source[i],
                data->recursion_deph)]++;
    }
}

static void process_bucket_inserter_thread(bucket_inserter_thread_data* data) {
    size_t bucket_index;
    size_t i;
    unsigned datum;

    for (i = data->from_index; i != data->to_index; ++i) {
        datum = data->source[i];
        bucket_index = get_bucket_index(datum, data->recursion_depth);
        data->target[data->start_index_map[bucket_index] + 
                     data->processed_map[bucket_index]++] = datum;
    }
}

static void process_sorter_thread(array_t* data) {
    size_t i;
    task* t;

    for (i = 0; i != array_t_size(data); ++i) {
        t = array_t_get(data, i);

        if (t->threads > 1) {
            parallel_radix_sort_impl(t->source,
                                     t->target,
                                     t->threads,
                                     t->recursion_depth,
                                     t->from_index,
                                     t->to_index);
        } else {
            radix_sort_impl_no_threads(t->source,
                                       t->target,
                                       t->recursion_depth,
                                       t->from_index,
                                       t->to_index);
        }
    }
}

#ifdef _WIN32

static DWORD WINAPI count_bucket_sizes_thread_func_win(LPVOID parameter) {
    bucket_size_counter_thread_data* thread_data =
        (bucket_size_counter_thread_data*) parameter;

    process_bucket_size_counter_thread(thread_data);
    return 0;
}

#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))

static void* count_bucket_sizes_thread_func_pthreads(void* parameter) {
    bucket_size_counter_thread_data* thread_data =
        (bucket_size_counter_thread_data*) parameter;

    process_bucket_size_counter_thread(thread_data);
    return NULL;
}

#endif

#ifdef _WIN32

static DWORD WINAPI insert_to_buckets_thread_func_win(LPVOID parameter) {
    bucket_inserter_thread_data* thread_data =
        (bucket_inserter_thread_data*) parameter;

    process_bucket_inserter_thread(thread_data);
    return 0;
}

#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))

static void* insert_to_buckets_thread_func_pthreads(void* parameter) {
    bucket_inserter_thread_data* thread_data =
        (bucket_inserter_thread_data*) parameter;

    process_bucket_inserter_thread(thread_data);
    return NULL;
}

#endif

#ifdef _WIN32

static DWORD WINAPI sort_buckets_thread_func_win(LPVOID parameter) {
    array_t* thread_data = (array_t*) parameter;
    process_sorter_thread(thread_data);
    return 0;
}

#elif defined(__unix__) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))

static void* sort_buckets_thread_func_pthreads(void* parameter) {
    array_t* thread_data = (array_t*) parameter;
    process_sorter_thread(thread_data);
    return NULL;
}

#endif

static void insertion_sort(unsigned* data, size_t length) {
    size_t i;
    signed long j;
    unsigned datum;

    for (i = 1; i != length; ++i) {
        datum = data[i];
        j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && data[j] > datum) {
            data[j + 1] = data[j];
            --j;
        }

        data[j + 1] = datum;
    }
}

static void merge(unsigned* source,
                  unsigned* target,
                  size_t left_index,
                  size_t left_bound,
                  size_t right_bound) {

    size_t right_index = left_bound;
    size_t target_index = left_index;

    while (left_index < left_bound && right_index < right_bound) {
        target[target_index++] = source[left_index] < source[right_index] ?
            source[left_index++] :
            source[right_index++];
    }

    memcpy(target + target_index,
           source + left_index,
           sizeof(unsigned) * (left_bound - left_index));

    memcpy(target + target_index,
           source + right_index,
           sizeof(unsigned) * (right_bound - right_index));
}

static void radix_sort_mergesort(unsigned* source,
                                 unsigned* target,
                                 size_t recursion_depth,
                                 size_t from_index,
                                 size_t to_index) {

    unsigned* s;
    unsigned* t;
    unsigned* temp;

    int even;

    size_t i;
    size_t left_bound;
    size_t left_index;
    size_t offset = from_index;
    size_t passes = 0;
    size_t range_length;
    size_t right_bound;
    size_t runs;
    size_t run_index;
    size_t run_width;

    range_length = to_index - from_index;
    s = source;
    t = target;

    runs = range_length / INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD;

    for (i = 0; i != runs; ++i) {
        insertion_sort(source + offset, INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD);
        offset += INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD;
    }

    if (range_length % INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD != 0) {
        /* Sort the rightmost run that is smaller than */
    /* INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD.                   */
        insertion_sort(source + offset, to_index - offset);
        runs++;
    }

    run_width = INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD;

    while (runs != 1) {
        passes++;
        run_index = 0;

        for (; run_index < runs - 1; run_index += 2) {
            left_index = from_index + run_index * run_width;
            left_bound = left_index + run_width;
            right_bound = MIN(left_bound + run_width, to_index);

            merge(s,
                  t,
                  left_index,
                  left_bound,
                  right_bound);
        }

        if (run_index < runs) {
            memcpy(t + from_index + run_index * run_width,
                   s + from_index + run_index * run_width,
                   sizeof(unsigned) * (range_length - run_index * run_width));
        }

        runs = (runs / 2) + (runs % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        temp = s;
        s = t;
        t = temp;
        run_width *= 2;
    }

    even = (passes % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;

    if (recursion_depth % 2 == 1) {
        if (even == 1) {
            memcpy(target + from_index, /* Destination */
                   source + from_index,    /* Source      */
                   sizeof(unsigned) * (to_index - from_index));
        }
    }
    else {
        /* Here, recursion_depth % 2 == 0 holds: */
        if (even == 0) {
            memcpy(source + from_index, /* Destination */
                   target + from_index,    /* Source      */
                   sizeof(unsigned) * (to_index - from_index));
        }
    }
}

static void radix_sort_impl_no_threads(unsigned* source,
                                       unsigned* target,
                                       size_t recursion_depth,
                                       size_t from_index,
                                       size_t to_index) {
    size_t bucket_key;
    size_t i;
    size_t bucket_size_map[BUCKETS];
    size_t processed_map[BUCKETS];
    size_t range_length;
    size_t start_index_map[BUCKETS];
    unsigned datum;

    range_length = to_index - from_index;

    if (range_length <= MERGESORT_THRESHOLD) {
        radix_sort_mergesort(source,
                             target,
                             recursion_depth,
                             from_index,
                             to_index);
        return;
    }

    memset(bucket_size_map, 0, BUCKETS * sizeof(size_t));
    memset(start_index_map, 0, BUCKETS * sizeof(size_t));
    memset(processed_map, 0, BUCKETS * sizeof(size_t));

    /* Compute the size of each bucket: */
    for (i = from_index; i != to_index; i++) {
        bucket_size_map[get_bucket_index(source[i], recursion_depth)]++;
    }

    /* Initialize thee start index map: */
    start_index_map[0] = from_index;

    for (i = 1; i != BUCKETS; ++i) {
        start_index_map[i] = start_index_map[i - 1]
                           + bucket_size_map[i - 1];
    }

    /* Insert the data from 'source' into their */
    /* respective position in 'target': */
    for (i = from_index; i != to_index; ++i) {
        datum = source[i];
        bucket_key = get_bucket_index(datum, recursion_depth);
        target[start_index_map[bucket_key] + 
               processed_map[bucket_key]++] = datum;
    }

    if (recursion_depth == sizeof(unsigned) - 1) {
        memcpy(source + from_index, /* Destination */
               target + from_index, /* Source      */
               sizeof(unsigned) * (to_index - from_index));

        /* There is nowhere to recur, return. */
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i != BUCKETS; ++i) {
        if (bucket_size_map[i] != 0) {
            radix_sort_impl_no_threads(target,
                                       source,
                                       recursion_depth + 1,
                                       start_index_map[i],
                                       start_index_map[i] + 
                                           bucket_size_map[i]);
        }
    }
}

void radix_sort(unsigned* data, size_t length) {
    unsigned* buffer;

    if (length < 2) {
        return;
    }

    buffer = malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * length);
    radix_sort_impl_no_threads(data, buffer, 0, 0, length);
    free(buffer);
}

static void parallel_radix_sort_impl(unsigned* source,
                                     unsigned* target,
                                     size_t threads,
                                     size_t recursion_depth,
                                     size_t from_index,
                                     size_t to_index) {
    size_t bucket_key;
    size_t f;
    size_t i;
    size_t idx;
    size_t j;
    size_t list_index;
    size_t number_of_nonempty_buckets;
    size_t optimal_subrange_length;
    size_t packed;
    size_t range_length;
    size_t spawn_degree;
    size_t start;
    size_t subrange_length;
    size_t sz;
    size_t sz2;
    size_t tmp;
    size_t* partial_bucket_size_map;
    size_t* thread_count_map;
    size_t bucket_size_map[BUCKETS] = { 0 };
    size_t start_index_map[BUCKETS];
    size_t** processed_map;
    bucket_size_counter_thread_data* bucket_size_counter_threads_data;
    bucket_inserter_thread_data* bucket_inserter_threads_data;
    array_t array_of_task_arrays;
    array_t bucket_index_list_array;
    array_t non_empty_bucket_indices;
    array_t* arr2;
    task* t;

#ifdef _WIN32
    HANDLE windows_thread_handle;
    HANDLE* win_thread_handles;
#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))
    pthread_t pthread_handle;
    pthread_t* unix_thread_ids;
#endif

    range_length = to_index - from_index;

    if (range_length <= MERGESORT_THRESHOLD) {
        radix_sort_mergesort(source,
                             target,
                             recursion_depth,
                             from_index,
                             to_index);
        return;
    }

    if (threads < 2) {
        radix_sort_impl_no_threads(source,
                                   target,
                                   recursion_depth,
                                   from_index,
                                   to_index);
        return;
    }

    bucket_size_counter_threads_data =
        malloc(threads * sizeof(*bucket_size_counter_threads_data));

    start = from_index;
    subrange_length = range_length / threads;

#ifdef _WIN32
    win_thread_handles = malloc(threads * sizeof(HANDLE));
#elif defined(__unix__) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))
    unix_thread_ids = malloc(threads * sizeof(pthread_t));
#endif

    for (i = 0; i != threads - 1; ++i) {
        bucket_size_counter_threads_data[i].source = source;
        bucket_size_counter_threads_data[i].recursion_deph = recursion_depth;
        bucket_size_counter_threads_data[i].from_index = start;
        bucket_size_counter_threads_data[i].to_index = start += subrange_length;

        memset(&(bucket_size_counter_threads_data[i]
            .local_bucket_size_map),
            0,
            BUCKETS * sizeof(size_t));

#ifdef _WIN32

        win_thread_handles[i] =
            CreateThread(NULL,
                         0,
                         count_bucket_sizes_thread_func_win,
                         &bucket_size_counter_threads_data[i],
                         0,
                         NULL);

#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))

        pthread_create(&pthread_handle,
                       NULL,
                       count_bucket_sizes_thread_func_pthreads,
                       &bucket_size_counter_threads_data[i]);

        unix_thread_ids[i] = pthread_handle;

#endif
    }

    /* Process the rightmost bucket in THIS thread. No need to spawn */
    /* any more.                                                     */
    bucket_size_counter_threads_data[threads - 1].source = source;
    bucket_size_counter_threads_data[threads - 1].recursion_deph =
        recursion_depth;

    bucket_size_counter_threads_data[threads - 1].from_index = start;
    bucket_size_counter_threads_data[threads - 1].to_index = to_index;

    memset(&(bucket_size_counter_threads_data[threads - 1]
        .local_bucket_size_map),
        0,
        BUCKETS * sizeof(size_t));

    /* Run the rightmost thread routine in THIS thread. */
    /* No need to span another thread:                  */
    process_bucket_size_counter_thread(
        &bucket_size_counter_threads_data[threads - 1]);

    /* Wait for all the bucket counters: */
    for (i = 0; i != threads - 1; ++i) {
#ifdef _WIN32
        WaitForSingleObject(win_thread_handles[i], INFINITE);
#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))
        pthread_join(unix_thread_ids[i], NULL);
#endif
    }

    /* Build the global bucket size map for the entire sorting range: */
    for (i = 0; i != threads; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j != BUCKETS; ++j) {
            bucket_size_map[j] +=
                bucket_size_counter_threads_data[i].local_bucket_size_map[j];
        }
    }

    number_of_nonempty_buckets = 0;

    for (i = 0; i != BUCKETS; ++i) {
        if (bucket_size_map[i] != 0) {
            number_of_nonempty_buckets++;
        }
    }

    spawn_degree = MIN(number_of_nonempty_buckets, threads);

    /* Prepare the starting indices of each bucket: */
    start_index_map[0] = from_index;

    for (i = 1; i != BUCKETS; ++i) {
        start_index_map[i] = start_index_map[i - 1]
                           + bucket_size_map[i - 1];
    }

    processed_map = malloc(spawn_degree * sizeof(size_t*));

    for (i = 0; i != spawn_degree; ++i) {
        processed_map[i] = calloc(BUCKETS, sizeof(size_t));
    }

    /* Make the preprocessed_map of each thread independent of the other. */
    for (i = 1; i != spawn_degree; ++i) {
        partial_bucket_size_map =
            (bucket_size_counter_threads_data[i - 1].local_bucket_size_map);

        for (j = 0; j != BUCKETS; ++j) {
            processed_map[i][j] = processed_map[i - 1][j]
                                + partial_bucket_size_map[j];
        }
    }

    start = from_index;

    bucket_inserter_threads_data =
        malloc(spawn_degree * sizeof(bucket_inserter_thread_data));

    for (i = 0; i != spawn_degree - 1; ++i) {
        bucket_inserter_threads_data[i].start_index_map = start_index_map;
        bucket_inserter_threads_data[i].processed_map = processed_map[i];
        bucket_inserter_threads_data[i].source = source;
        bucket_inserter_threads_data[i].target = target;
        bucket_inserter_threads_data[i].recursion_depth = recursion_depth;
        bucket_inserter_threads_data[i].from_index = start;
        bucket_inserter_threads_data[i].to_index = start += subrange_length;

#ifdef _WIN32

        win_thread_handles[i] =
            CreateThread(NULL,
                         0,
                         insert_to_buckets_thread_func_win,
                         &bucket_inserter_threads_data[i],
                         0,
                         NULL);

#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))

        pthread_create(&pthread_handle,
                       NULL,
                       insert_to_buckets_thread_func_pthreads,
                       &bucket_inserter_threads_data[i]);

        unix_thread_ids[i] = pthread_handle;

#endif
    }

    /* Process the rightmost bucket in THIS thread. No need to spawn */
    /* any more.                                                     */
    bucket_inserter_threads_data[spawn_degree - 1].start_index_map =
        start_index_map;

    bucket_inserter_threads_data[spawn_degree - 1].processed_map =
        processed_map[spawn_degree - 1];

    bucket_inserter_threads_data[spawn_degree - 1].source = source;
    bucket_inserter_threads_data[spawn_degree - 1].target = target;
    bucket_inserter_threads_data[spawn_degree - 1].recursion_depth =
        recursion_depth;

    bucket_inserter_threads_data[spawn_degree - 1].from_index = start;
    bucket_inserter_threads_data[spawn_degree - 1].to_index = to_index;

    process_bucket_inserter_thread(
        &bucket_inserter_threads_data[spawn_degree - 1]);

    /* Wait for all the bucket inserters: */
    for (i = 0; i != spawn_degree - 1; ++i) {
#ifdef _WIN32
        WaitForSingleObject(win_thread_handles[i], INFINITE);
#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))
        pthread_join(unix_thread_ids[i], NULL);
#endif
    }

    free(bucket_size_counter_threads_data);
    free(bucket_inserter_threads_data);

    for (i = 0; i != spawn_degree; ++i) {
        free(processed_map[i]);
    }

    free(processed_map);

    if (recursion_depth == sizeof(unsigned) - 1) {
        /* Nowhere to recur. */
        return;
    }

    array_t_init(&bucket_index_list_array, spawn_degree);

    for (i = 0; i != spawn_degree; ++i) {
        array_t* bucket_key_array = malloc(sizeof(array_t));
        array_t_init(bucket_key_array, number_of_nonempty_buckets);
        array_t_add(&bucket_index_list_array, bucket_key_array);
    }

    thread_count_map = calloc(spawn_degree, sizeof(size_t));

    for (i = 0; i != spawn_degree; ++i) {
        thread_count_map[i] = threads / spawn_degree;
    }

    for (i = 0; i != threads % spawn_degree; ++i) {
        ++thread_count_map[i];
    }

    array_t_init(&non_empty_bucket_indices, number_of_nonempty_buckets);

    for (bucket_key = 0; bucket_key != BUCKETS; ++bucket_key) {
        if (bucket_size_map[bucket_key] != 0) {
            array_t_add(&non_empty_bucket_indices, (void*) bucket_key);
        }
    }

    array_t_shuffle(&non_empty_bucket_indices);

    f = 0;
    j = 0;
    list_index = 0;
    optimal_subrange_length = range_length / spawn_degree;
    packed = 0;
    sz = array_t_size(&non_empty_bucket_indices);

    while (j != sz) {
        size_t bucket_key =
            (size_t) array_t_get(&non_empty_bucket_indices, j++);

        tmp = bucket_size_map[bucket_key];
        packed += tmp;

        if (packed >= optimal_subrange_length ||
            j == array_t_size(&non_empty_bucket_indices)) {

            packed = 0;

            for (i = f; i != j; ++i) {
                size_t bucket_key =
                    (size_t) array_t_get(&non_empty_bucket_indices, i);

                array_t* arr = array_t_get(&bucket_index_list_array,
                                           list_index);

                array_t_add(arr, (void*) bucket_key);
            }

            ++list_index;
            f = j;
        }
    }

    array_t_init(&array_of_task_arrays, spawn_degree);

    for (i = 0; i != spawn_degree; ++i) {
        array_t* task_array = malloc(sizeof(array_t));
        array_t_init(task_array, BUCKETS);
        arr2 = (array_t*) array_t_get(&bucket_index_list_array, i);
        sz = array_t_size(arr2);

        for (idx = 0; idx != sz; ++idx) {
            bucket_key = (size_t) array_t_get(arr2, idx);

            t = malloc(sizeof(task));

            t->source = target;
            t->target = source;
            t->threads = thread_count_map[i];
            t->recursion_depth = recursion_depth + 1;
            t->from_index = start_index_map[bucket_key];
            t->to_index = start_index_map[bucket_key]
                        + bucket_size_map[bucket_key];

            array_t_add(task_array, t);
        }

        array_t_add(&array_of_task_arrays, task_array);
    }

    for (i = 0; i != spawn_degree - 1; ++i) {
        array_t* task_array = array_t_get(&array_of_task_arrays, i);

#ifdef _WIN32

        win_thread_handles[i] =
            CreateThread(NULL,
                         0,
                         sort_buckets_thread_func_win,
                         task_array,
                         0,
                         NULL);

#elif defined(__unix__) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))

        pthread_create(&pthread_handle,
                       NULL,
                       sort_buckets_thread_func_pthreads,
                       task_array);

        unix_thread_ids[i] = pthread_handle;

#endif
    }

    /* Sort the rightmost thread in THIS thread. */
    /* No need to spawn one more thread.         */
    process_sorter_thread(
        array_t_get(
            &array_of_task_arrays,
            spawn_degree - 1));

    for (i = 0; i != spawn_degree - 1; ++i) {

#ifdef _WIN32
        WaitForSingleObject(win_thread_handles[i], INFINITE);
#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))
        pthread_join(unix_thread_ids[i], NULL);
#endif

    }

#ifdef _WIN32
    free(win_thread_handles);
#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))
    free(unix_thread_ids);
#endif

    sz = array_t_size(&array_of_task_arrays);

    for (i = 0; i != sz; ++i) {
        array_t* task_array = array_t_get(&array_of_task_arrays, i);

        sz2 = array_t_size(task_array);

        for (j = 0; j != sz2; ++j) {
            free(array_t_get(task_array, j));
        }

        array_t_destruct(task_array);
        free(task_array);
    }

    sz = array_t_size(&bucket_index_list_array);

    for (i = 0; i != sz; ++i) {
        array_t* array = array_t_get(&bucket_index_list_array, i);
        array_t_destruct(array);
        free(array);
    }

    free(thread_count_map);
    array_t_destruct(&array_of_task_arrays);
    array_t_destruct(&bucket_index_list_array);
    array_t_destruct(&non_empty_bucket_indices);
}

static void bitwise_radix_sort_impl(unsigned* data,
                                    size_t bucket_length,
                                    size_t bit_index) {

    size_t size_of_left_bucket;
    size_t size_of_right_bucket;

    unsigned bit_is_on;
    unsigned datum;
    unsigned mask;
    unsigned temp;

    if (bucket_length < 2) {
        /* Trivially sorted. */
        return;
    }

    size_of_left_bucket = 0;
    size_of_right_bucket = 0;
    mask = 1U << bit_index;

    /* Bucketize the current range: */
    while (size_of_left_bucket + size_of_right_bucket < bucket_length) {
        datum = data[size_of_left_bucket];
        bit_is_on = datum & mask;

        if (bit_is_on) {
            /* Kick the datum to the right 1-bucket: */
            temp = data[bucket_length - size_of_right_bucket - 1];
            data[bucket_length - size_of_right_bucket - 1] = datum;
            data[size_of_left_bucket] = temp;
            size_of_right_bucket++;
        }
        else {
            /* Omit the datum: */
            size_of_left_bucket++;
        }
    }

    /* Any bits to proceed? */
    if (bit_index > 0) {
        /* Sort the 0-bucket of this recursion level: */
        bitwise_radix_sort_impl(data,
                                size_of_left_bucket,
                                bit_index - 1);

        /* Sort the 1-bucket of this recursion level: */
        bitwise_radix_sort_impl(data + size_of_left_bucket,
                                size_of_right_bucket,
                                bit_index - 1);
    }
}

void bitwise_radix_sort(unsigned* data, size_t length) {
    bitwise_radix_sort_impl(data,
                            length,
                            sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
}

void parallel_radix_sort(unsigned* data, size_t length) {
    unsigned* buffer;
    size_t threads;

    if (length < 2) {
        return;
    }

    buffer = malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * length);
    threads = get_number_of_cpus();
    threads = MIN(threads, length / THREAD_THRESHOLD);
    parallel_radix_sort_impl(data, buffer, threads, 0, 0, length);
    free(buffer);
}
```

**Typical output**

```
Number of sorting threads: 8
Number of keys to sort: 50000000
Created the arrays in 2938 milliseconds.
qsort in 11015 milliseconds.
bitwise_radix_sort in 6391 milliseconds.
radix_sort in 1500 milliseconds.
parallel_radix_sort in 422 milliseconds.

Algorithms agree: 1

array1 is sorted: 1
array2 is sorted: 1
array3 is sorted: 1
array4 is sorted: 1
```

The above benchmark was run on a quad-core CPU.

**Critique request**

As always, I would like to hear anything that comes to mind.

Comment: What version of ANSI C are you using?

Comment: @pacmaninbw Oops, I thought ANSI C = C89. However, I use -ansi switch in Makefile. Will clarify the issue tomorrow, now tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `parallel_radix_sort_impl()` is over 400 lines of code. There must be some way to break this up into multiple functions. This is way too complex, and too difficult to understand and maintain. Back in 1989 this might have been accepted because of processor speed but it isn't acceptable now.

One of the differences between ANSI C in 1989 and K&R C in 1972 was that you could define variables where necessary rather than only at the top of the logic block. There is no reason to have all of your variables defined at the top of the function.

As mentioned in another answer there are newer C standards that might be more appropriate. C99 allows you to declare for loop control variables in the for loop. This would decrease the number of lines of code. Anything that decreases the number of lines of code decreases the number of faults in the code.

In 1991 I spent a year converting K&R C to ANSI C. The company I worked for felt it was necessary to convert the code. There are good reasons to follow newer standards.

Answer (score 3):

## Consider using C11 thread support

You are making your code compatible with C89, however that is a standard that is more than 30 years old, and we have advanced since then. C11 introduced support for [concurrency](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread). Consider using those functions in your program.

Of course it can happen that your build environment doesn't support C11 threads. To account for that possibility, you can write your own drop-in replacement for them. For example, create a c11threads.h file that contains:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L && !defined(__STDC_NO_THREADS__)
    #include <threads.h>
#else
#ifdef _WIN32
    ...
#elif defined (__unix__) || (defined (__APPLE__) && defined (__MACH__))
    #include <pthread.h>

    typedef pthread_t thrd_t;
    typedef int (*thrd_start_t)(void *);

    static int thrd_create(thrd_t *thr, thrd_start_t func, void *arg) {
        return pthread_create(thr, NULL, func, arg);
    }

    ...
#else
    #error "Unsupported platform."
#endif
```

The advantage of this is that your source file containing the radix sort implementation can now be written against a standard API without using `#ifdef`s all over the place.

One caveat is that C11 unfortunately made the existence of `<threads.h>` optional, but says `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` will be defined if it isn't present. However, many compilers used to forget to define this even if they were in C11 mode and did not provide `<threads.h>`, so you might need additional checks to cope with those compilers. Alternatively, if you have a build system you can have it check for the presence of `<threads.h>`.

## Buckets vs. `CHAR_BIT`

I see you define 256 buckets, with `BITS_PER_BUCKET` being 8, and at the same time you use `CHAR_BIT` in your code. However, what if `CHAR_BIT` is not 8? Will things still work correctly? Consider:

```
static size_t get_bucket_index(unsigned datum, size_t recursion_depth) {
    size_t bit_shift = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned)
                       - (recursion_depth + 1) * BITS_PER_BUCKET;

    return (((size_t) datum) >> bit_shift) & BUCKET_MASK;
}
```

The shift operation has undefined behavior if the right hand side is negative or is greater or equal to the number of bits in the left hand side. It's unlikely that `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned)` will be too large (but theoretically, `size_t` is allowed to be smaller than `unsigned`). However, if `BITS_PER_BUCKET` is larger than `CHAR_BIT`, then the result of the subtraction would be negative, but since it's stored in a `size_t`, it will wrap around and become a huge number.

To avoid this problem, ensure `BITS_PER_BUCKET` is equal to `CHAR_BIT`, and perhaps derive the other constants from it as well:

```
#define BUCKETS (1 << CHAR_BIT)

static const size_t BITS_PER_BUCKET = CHAR_BIT;
static const size_t BUCKET_MASK = BUCKETS - 1;
```